# Unique Pointer attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

Hello I am trying to use pointers and learning the basics on unique pointers in `C++`. Below is my code I have commented the line of code in main function. to debug the problem However, I am unable to do so. What am I missing ? Is my `move()` in the `insertNode()` incorrect ? The error I get is below the code :

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>

struct node{
    int data;
    std::unique_ptr<node> next;
};


void print(std::unique_ptr<node>head){
        while (head)
            std::cout << head->data<<std::endl;
    }


std::unique_ptr<node> insertNode(std::unique_ptr<node>head, int value){
        node newNode;
        newNode.data = value;
        //head is empty
        if (!head){
            return std::make_unique<node>(newNode);
        }
        else{
            //head points to an existing list
            newNode.next = move(head->next);
            return std::make_unique<node>(newNode);
        }
    }



auto main() -> int
{
    //std::unique_ptr<node>head;
    //for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    //  //head = insertNode(head, i);
    //}
}
```

**ERROR**
std::unique_ptr>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function

Comment: You can't copy unique_ptrs. Your print function can't work without moving the unique_ptr you use as a parameter, making it empty. I would make the parameter `const node&`. As print function doesn't keep any reference to the parameter after it returns, it doesn't need to know about how it is managed.

Comment: `print` is broken in other ways too -- right now it is an infinite loop.  And `insertNode` needs to be pass-by-reference also

Comment: auto main() -> int. really?

Comment: You shouldn't really be using `unique_ptr` like this. For example, by passing a `unique_ptr` to your print function, you're implying that it is taking ownership of the pointer; when really that isn't the case. The enclosing scope of a `unique_ptr` is said to be the sole owner of it (which is why it's called unique); you can move this ownership but not share/copy it. A `shared_ptr`, on the other hand, represents ownership that is shared; a raw/weak pointer or reference (probably what your print function should accept... `const` qualified) generally indicates a lack of ownership.

Answer (score 6):

Aside from other small problems, the main issue is this line:

```
return std::make_unique<node>(newNode);
```

You are trying to construct a unique pointer to a new node, passing `newNode` to the copy constructor of `node`. However, the copy constructor of `node` is deleted, since `node` contains a non-copyable type (i.e. `std::unique_ptr<node>`).

You should pass a `std::move(newNode)` instead, but this is problematic since you create the node on the stack and it will be destroyed at the exit from the function.

Using a `std::unique_ptr` here is a bad idea in my opinion, since, for example, to print the list (or insert into the list), you need to `std::move` the `head` (so you lose it) and so on. I think you're much better off with a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Diagnosis is correct, but recommendation to use `shared_ptr` is baseless.  There's no reason that any of this code should be copying smart pointers.

Comment: @BenVoigt I actually agree with your comment, I should probably remove my answer.

Comment: Perhaps just the last paragraph should be changed or improved.  The rest is helpful.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'd like to make this answer better, can you suggest how? I grant you the right to edit and add it to my answer, without any complaint from my side. In general, you'd need to copy at least the "head" of the list, so what kind of pointer would you'd use for?

Comment: I rather liked WhozCraig's method in his now-deleted answer, that the unique_ptr that used to hold the head now holds the new head.  There isn't really a reason to **copy** the head pointer, because the action of linking another node in front makes it no longer the head.  Actually pass-by-value to `insertHead`, as used in the question, is not so bad after all, since it forces the caller to be aware that the old head pointer is being taken away from them.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and indeed using a `shared_ptr` works.

Using the smart pointer as an argument in the function copies the pointer (not the data it points to), and this causes the `unique_ptr` to reset and delete the data it was previously pointing at- hence we get that "attempting to reference a deleted function" error. If you use a `shared_ptr` this will simply increment the reference count and de-increment it once you are out of the scope of that function.

The comments in the answers above suggest that using a shared_ptr is baseless. These answers were written before the C++17 standard and it is my understanding that we should be using the most updated versions of the language, hence the `shared_ptr` is appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why we have to expose node type to user in any case. Whole thingamajig of C++ is ***to write more code in order to write less code later***, as one of my tutors said.

We would like to encapsulate everything and leave no head or tail  (pun intended) of node to user. Very simplistic interface would look like:

```
struct list
{
private:
  struct node {
      int data;
      std::unique_ptr<node> next;
      node(int data) : data{data}, next{nullptr} {}
  }; 
  std::unique_ptr<node>  head;
public:   
  list() : head{nullptr} {};

  void push(int data);
  int pop();

  ~list(); // do we need this?
};
```

The implementation does something what Ben Voigt mentioned:

```
void list::push(int data) 
{
    auto temp{std::make_unique<node>(data)};
    if(head) 
    {
        temp->next = std::move(head);
        head = std::move(temp);
    } else 
    {
        head = std::move(temp);
    }
}

int list::pop() 
{
   if(head == nullptr) {
      return 0; /* Return some default. */
      /* Or do unthinkable things to user. Throw things at him or throw exception. */
   }  
   auto temp = std::move(head);
   head = std::move(temp->next);
   return temp->data;
}
```

We actually need a destructor which would NOT be recursive if list will be really large. Our stack may explode because node's destructor would call unique_ptr's destructor then would call managed node's destructor, which would call unique_ptr's destructor... ad nauseatum.

```
void list::clear() { while(head) head = std::move(head->next); }

list::~list() { clear(); }
```

After that default destructor would ping `unique_ptr` destructor only once for `head`, no recursive iterations.

If we want to iterate through list without popping node, we'd use `get()` within some method designed to address that task.

```
Node *head = list.head.get();
/* ... */
head = head->next.get();
```

`get()` return raw pointer without  breaking management.

Answer (score 0):

How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24591763/13792395) example, in addition to the sample code, he also mentioned some principles:

> when you need to "assign" -- use std::move and when you need to just traverse, use get()